# Transform a Fixed width file in Mule

Tags: mule

What is the best way to transform a fixed width file. Based on certain criteria i need to skip certain rows in the fixed width file. Should a custom java component be written for this or can some inbuilt transformers be used. I tried to search in the Mule docs but unable to find a suitable answer hence posting the question here.

Answer (score 0):

If your file has common delimiters for the fields and supported file extension then data-mapper will be able to transform to csv, json etc. You may be able to use the other hard coded transformers.

For anything else you can extend the transform class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have following content in your file .

**001MONSTARTWORK
001TUEPROGRESSWORK
001WEDTAKEABREAK
001THURESUMEWORK
001FRIFINISHWORK
001SATCHILLDOWN
001SUNGRABABEER**

Below DW Script ll split the data and ll format it as JSON.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
(payload splitBy "\n") map {
    Id:$[0..2],
    Day:$[3..5],
    Shout:$[6..18]
}
```